# How to import my own class in Python: "{class} imported but unused"?

Tags: python, class, python-import

I am trying to do this assignment, but I am not sure why I cannot import the class Nation I created? I get an error on saving - "nation imported but unused"? Then if I run it I get a Traceback error

```
import pickle
class Nation:
    def __init__(self,name,continent,population,landArea):
        self.name=name
        self.continent=continent
        self.population=float(population)
        self.landArea=float(landArea)
    def getCon(self):
        return self.continent
    def popDensity(self):
        return ((10**6 * self.population)/self.landArea)

CD = dict()
file = open("UN.txt","r")
for line in file:
    ls = line.strip()
    ls=line.split(',')
    N = Nation(ls[0],ls[1],ls[2],ls[3])
    CD[ls[0]] = N
file.close()
file=open("nationsDict.dat","wb")
pickle.dump(CD,file)
file.close()

import pickle
import nation as nation
```

Comment: although you can import from any line you like in python, generally people put their import statements at the top of their code. Why do you have `import pickle` and `import nation as nation` at the end there?

Comment: I think the code block represents the content of multiple source files? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: also the way you import functions or classes you created is to make an `__init__.py` in your directory, define the class in a file `nation.py` and then include that in another file like `main.py` with the import statement `from nation import Nation` because lowercase n nation is the filename and upper case N Nation is the classname

Comment: more info can be found here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html and here: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/